# Redefine a value during runtime inside another macro

Tags: environments

I would like to redefine a value **during runtime**. 
More precisely, I'm creating my own environment and in the preamble I would like to change a value and set it back afterward.

```
\newenvironment{reptheorem}[1]%
{%
\makeatletter%
\def\@thmcounterend{new}%In this environment, @thmcounterend has a new value
\makeatother%
}%
{%
\makeatletter%
\def\@thmcounterend{old}%We reset @thmcounterend to its previous value. 
\makeatother%
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't work since the \def is not executed when the environment is created but later.

Any idea?

Comment: You use the word "counter" but a `\def` means to use it as a macro.  If `@thmcounterend` is, in fact, a pre-existing counter from another package, for example, the proper use of counters is not with `\def`, but with `\setcounter{@thmcounterend}{value}`.  With your question, there is not enough information to definitively help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are given much too late. The category codes are important at the definition time of the environment, when `\@thmcounterend` gets tokenized:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{reptheorem}[1]{%
  \def\@thmcounterend{new}%
}{%
  \def\@thmcounterend{old}%
}
\makeatother
```